# Correctly fit image with FadeInImage Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

[image]

Hello, I'm using FadeInImage with a placeholder and an image, but the second image do not cover the complete parent, I'm using fit:BoxFit.cover but any way the result is not good. Anyone knows how to make it possible. This is my actual code. The 'document[_newsImage] is an URL took from CloudFirebase.

```
      Widget _itemCard(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document, int index) {
    return new Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0),
        child: new Card(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
              height: 250.0,
              child: new FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                placeholder: 'assets/images/esperanza.jpg',
                image: document[_newsImage],
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              )),
          Container(
              height: 150.0,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 0.0, 16.0, 0.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            document[_newsTitle],
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                          Text(document[_newsDate])
                        ]),
                    Text(
                      document[_textShortDescription],
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 14),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () => onPressed(context, document),
                            child: Text(
                              _stringShowMore,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo),
                            )),
                        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.share), onPressed: null)
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ))
        ])));
  }
```

Comment: could you add the code of the item widget?

Comment: @diegoveloper done, I added the complete itemCard, it goes inside a ListView.builder.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try these changes:

- Size the container to fill the width
- Add the height inside the FadeInImage

  ```
    new Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: new FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
          placeholder: 'assets/images/esperanza.jpg',
          image: document[_newsImage],
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          height: 250.0,
        )),
  ```

Comment: but the size of the placeholder image is also changed !

Comment: you got any solution for this issue ?

Comment: I got a better result by replacing the static `height` with `double.maxFinite`. Here I got the desired `cover` result.